# Why is helper thread not exiting in this python script?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, global-variables, python-multithreading

I have three files:

**helper.py**

```
from globalvariables import *

global exit_signal
global exited_signal

def helperstart():

    global exited_signal

    while True:
        if exit_signal is True:
            exited_signal = True
            print ('Exiting from helper thread')
            return
```

**main.py**

```
from globalvariables import *
import threading
import helper

global exit_signal
global exited_signal

def mainstart():

    global exit_signal

    helper_thread = threading.Thread(target = helper.helperstart)
    input ('Press <enter> to start the thread')
    helper_thread.start()
    input ('Press <enter> to end the thread')
    exit_signal = True

    # check if helper has exited
    if exited_signal is True:
        print ('Helper exited successfully')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainstart()
```

**globalvariables.py**

```
exit_signal = False
exited_signal = False
```

From `main.py`, the value of `exit_signal` should be edited to True. This should make the helper thread exit. But it is not exiting. I've tried printing the value of `exit_signal` from `helperstart()` function and it keeps showing as False. So, the `main.py` isn't editing the variable properly. Please help me figure out why.

Comment: Try using `globalvariables.exit_signal` and `globalvariables.exited_signal` as the variables are declared in that imported file. However, I would suggest not using the term global variables.

Comment: @BasJansen But I'm importing using `from globalvariables import *`, so I should not be adding the module name before the variables. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Touché, I am having a crack at this out of personal interest in threating (haven't played around with it in ages).

Comment: In my actual code, I found that I'm able to edit the variables from different threads but not from the main file. Maybe this could give a clue as to what the problem is. However, the question I've posted above is complete. You may disregard this comment.